# matplotlib. How do I switch between subplots, rather than replotting them from scratch?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create a figure and fill it with a couple of subplots.

As new data arrives, I'd like to draw it on a given subplot.

How do I switch between subplots so that I don't have to create new subplot objects each time?

Example:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure,

figure()
subplot(2,1,1)
subplot(2,1,2)

# now go back and plot something on subplot 1 ...?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assign subplot to a variable:

```
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()

plt1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
plt2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
```

Then you can draw lines and points and whatever else you want with references to `plt1` and `plt2`

Take a look at the [reference](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) for everything you can do with the plot.